# Process unhandled rejections in Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, when-js

Follow up question re. [trap when.js unhandled rejections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689143/trap-when-js-unhandled-rejections/29689261)

the Node.js process.on() example prevents the normal console/prettymonitor output from displaying. Is there a way to retain this. Also the docs show: process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, key) not ..(promise,reason). ref: http://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/debug-api.md

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be related to promises or when.js at all, the process.on hook for unhandled rejection cannot prevent output from displaying or do whatever it is that you are claiming.

Comment: @Esailija If I remove the unhandledRejection handler I see the prettymonitor output. If I leave it in place I just see the plain output  sent to console.